# What is the number of ways to distribute grades A, B, C or D among $3$ students so that no two of them have same grades?

Tags: combinatorics

*Question*: What is the number of ways to distribute grades A, B, C or D among $3$ students so that no two of them have same grades.

My approach:

Total Ways to distribute Grades $=4\cdot4\cdot4=64$
Ways in which all $3$ students have same grade $= 1$
Ways in which $2$ students have same grade $= 1\cdot1\cdot3(3)=9$

$\implies$ Total ways in which no two students have same grade $=64-1-9=54$.

Please advise if my approach is correct.

Comment: There $\binom{4}{3} = 4$ ways to choose three grades.  Then there are $3! = 6$ ways to rearrange each group (i.e. give to a different student) thus there are $4 * 6 = 24$ ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ways exactly 3 students have the same grade should be 4 since there are 4 grades.

Ways exactly 2 students have the same grade should be $3\cdot 4 \cdot 3$, first you choose the guy who has a different grade to the other 2, which has 3 choices, then you choose the actual grades.

But it's easier to just do this directly. The question in other words ask that each student has a different grade, so this is $4\cdot 3\cdot 2 = 24$, the same answer.

Comment: To clarify a bit: For the first student you have $4$ grades available, for the second just $3$, and only $2$ remain for the last one.